# Jboss EAP 6 : HttpRequest http-header validation

Tags: jboss, containers

As a security measure my organization requires me to validate a header attribute to allow a request to go through the business rules. Where would I need to configure this in the Jboss eap 6.3? This configuration was done before me and i am not sure how it was achieved before in the earlier jboss 5.x. Please let me know how would I configure the container security without making any application changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we had a different way of handling it. We used the single sign on feature of Jboss 5 and at the container level validated the header. When the header was validated, a generic role name was exposed which was used by Applications to limit the resources to the specific role name.

Comment: Like mentioned by @doctau we are going with the Global valve to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a Global Valve, which is like a servlet filter but with more access to JBossWeb (Tomcat) internals and applies to all requests. Details are in the documentation at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-Global_Valves.html

That is not portable between containers, and will not work in WildFly or EAP 7+ since the web container has changed from JBossWeb to Undertow.

Comment: I had not said the same in my answer that I found, but that is the option that we are going to use for EAP 6. We should be having it ready in the next week or so. But interesting why would you say EAP 7+ would not support this? My impression was EAP 6+ was already using wildfly and jbossweb now uses a tomcat fork.

Comment: EAP 4.x, 5 and 6 use JBossWeb, which is a fork of Tomcat as you say. Wildfly 8, 9 (and presumably later versions) use a new web container called Undertow. Since Valves are a Tomcat class, they aren't supported in Undertow (and so Wildfly), although there is an equivalent.

Comment: Doctau Jboss AS 7 is Jboss EAP 6. And wildfly is part of Jboss EAP 6+ .http://planet.jboss.org/post/jboss_eap_and_wildfly_a_symbiotic_relationship. And thanks for correcting my understanding of the web container. i did not read it right previously that JbossWeb is now Underflow. http://www.slideshare.net/dandreadis/2013-09lausannejug

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, this has to be done in applications. Not sure if this can be done generally in JBoss configuration.

Try this https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_add_validation_logic_to_HttpServletRequest

Comment: We had a different way of using. I posted that as an answer to the question.